# Running multiple variants of a function asynchronously in Python

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, multiprocessing, user-defined-functions

How can I run multiple processes pool where I process `run1-3` asynchronously, with a multi processing tool in python.

```
def Numbers(number):
   value = number * 10 /33
   return value

run1 = Numbers(10)
run2 = Numbers(2)
run3 = Numbers(55)
```

Comment: It is doubtful that due to the overhead of creating processes and transferring parameters and results from one address space to another that you would see a performance improvement with such a trivial function as `Numbers`. In fact, I would expect performance to degrade.

Comment: Small nitpick, function names should be lowercase (more precisely, snake_case). Only class names should use CamelCase. Someone reading your code would reasonably assume `Numbers` was a class reference and might make some incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

simple usage of [multiprocessing.Pool()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
import multiprocessing                                # import package
with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool:               # 3 processes
    run1, run2, run3 = pool.map(Numbers, [10,2,55]) # map input & output
```

Comment: be sure to always use `if __name__ == "__main__":` with multiprocessing. child processes must import the main file, and you can't create grandchildren during the import (it's a runtime error)